# babe-worker failed after upgrade to 0.9.42

Tags: error, nodes, upgrade

After upgrading to 0.9.42, we have `ERROR tokio-runtime-worker sc_service::task_manager: Essential task babe-worker failed. Shutting down service.` error starting the node using `cargo run -- --dev`. Using `cargo run -- --dev --sealing=instant` the node starts correctly.

The update requires a few modifications concerning babe in `node/src/`:

```rs
diff --git a/node/src/command/key.rs b/node/src/command/key.rs
index 655ebc2..6aa6ffe 100644
--- a/node/src/command/key.rs
+++ b/node/src/command/key.rs
@@ -20,7 +20,7 @@ use sc_cli::{
 use sc_keystore::LocalKeystore;
 use sc_service::config::{BasePath, KeystoreConfig};
 use sp_core::crypto::{AccountId32, KeyTypeId, SecretString};
-use sp_keystore::{SyncCryptoStore, SyncCryptoStorePtr};
+use sp_keystore::{Keystore, KeystorePtr};
 use std::sync::Arc;
 
 #[derive(Debug, clap::Subcommand)]
@@ -82,18 +82,17 @@ impl GenSessionKeysCmd {
         let mut public_keys_bytes = Vec::with_capacity(128);
         for (key_type_id, crypto_scheme) in KEY_TYPES {
             let (keystore, public) = match self.keystore_params.keystore_config(&config_dir)? {
-                (_, KeystoreConfig::Path { path, password }) => {
+                KeystoreConfig::Path { path, password } => {
                     let public =
                         with_crypto_scheme!(crypto_scheme, to_vec(&suri, password.clone()))?;
-                    let keystore: SyncCryptoStorePtr =
-                        Arc::new(LocalKeystore::open(path, password)?);
+                    let keystore: KeystorePtr = Arc::new(LocalKeystore::open(path, password)?);
                     (keystore, public)
                 }
                 _ => unreachable!("keystore_config always returns path and password; qed"),
             };
 
-            SyncCryptoStore::insert_unknown(&*keystore, key_type_id, &suri, &public[..])
-                .map_err(|_| Error::KeyStoreOperation)?;
+            Keystore::insert(&*keystore, key_type_id, &suri, &public[..])
+                .map_err(|_| Error::KeystoreOperation)?;
 
             public_keys_bytes.extend_from_slice(&public[..]);
         }
diff --git a/node/src/service.rs b/node/src/service.rs
index 258b8af..8cb3132 100644
--- a/node/src/service.rs
+++ b/node/src/service.rs
@@ -238,13 +238,6 @@ where
         RuntimeApiCollection<StateBackend = sc_client_api::StateBackendFor<FullBackend, Block>>,
     Executor: sc_executor::NativeExecutionDispatch + 'static,
 {
-    if config.keystore_remote.is_some() {
-        return Err(ServiceError::Other(
-            "Remote Keystores are not supported.".to_owned(),
-        ));
-    }
-    // TODO deprecated ?
-
     let telemetry = config
         .telemetry_endpoints
         .clone()
@@ -311,7 +304,7 @@ where
         )
     } else {
         let slot_duration = babe_link.config().slot_duration();
-        let import_queue = sc_consensus_babe::import_queue(
+        let (import_queue, _) = sc_consensus_babe::import_queue(
             babe_link.clone(),
             babe_block_import.clone(),
             Some(Box::new(justification_import)),
@@ -347,13 +340,6 @@ where
     })
 }
 
-fn remote_keystore(_url: &str) -> Result<Arc<LocalKeystore>, &'static str> {
-    // FIXME: here would the concrete keystore be built,
-    //        must return a concrete type (NOT `LocalKeystore`) that
-    //        implements `CryptoStore` and `SyncCryptoStore`
-    Err("Remote Keystore not supported.")
-}
-
 /// Builds a new service for a full client.
 pub fn new_full<RuntimeApi, Executor>(
     mut config: Configuration,
@@ -373,24 +359,12 @@ where
         backend,
         mut task_manager,
         import_queue,
-        mut keystore_container,
+        keystore_container,
         select_chain,
         transaction_pool,
         other: (block_import, babe_link, grandpa_link, mut telemetry),
     } = new_partial::<RuntimeApi, Executor>(&config, sealing.is_manual_consensus())?;
 
-    if let Some(url) = &config.keystore_remote {
-        match remote_keystore(url) {
-            Ok(k) => keystore_container.set_remote_keystore(k),
-            Err(e) => {
-                return Err(ServiceError::Other(format!(
-                    "Error hooking up remote keystore for {}: {}",
-                    url, e
-                )))
-            }
-        };
-    } // TODO deprecated ?
-
     let grandpa_protocol_name = sc_consensus_grandpa::protocol_standard_name(
         &client
             .block_hash(0)
@@ -415,7 +389,6 @@ where
     let (network, system_rpc_tx, tx_handler_controller, network_starter, sync_service) =
         sc_service::build_network(sc_service::BuildNetworkParams {
             config: &config,
-            //net_config: net_config,
             client: client.clone(),
             transaction_pool: transaction_pool.clone(),
             spawn_handle: task_manager.spawn_handle(),
@@ -489,7 +462,7 @@ where
             let babe_consensus_data_provider =
                 sc_consensus_manual_seal::consensus::babe::BabeConsensusDataProvider::new(
                     client.clone(),
-                    keystore_container.sync_keystore(),
+                    keystore_container.keystore(),
                     babe_link.epoch_changes().clone(),
                     vec![(
                         sp_consensus_babe::AuthorityId::from(
@@ -532,7 +505,7 @@ where
             let client_clone = client.clone();
             let slot_duration = babe_link.config().slot_duration();
             let babe_config = sc_consensus_babe::BabeParams {
-                keystore: keystore_container.sync_keystore(),
+                keystore: keystore_container.keystore(),
                 client: client.clone(),
                 select_chain,
                 block_import,
@@ -581,7 +554,7 @@ where
 
     let rpc_extensions_builder = {
         let client = client.clone();
-        //let keystore = keystore_container.sync_keystore();
+        //let keystore = keystore_container.keystore();
         let pool = transaction_pool.clone();
         //let select_chain = select_chain.clone();
         //let chain_spec = config.chain_spec.cloned_box();
@@ -611,7 +584,7 @@ where
         network: network.clone(),
         sync_service: sync_service.clone(),
         client,
-        keystore: keystore_container.sync_keystore(),
+        keystore: keystore_container.keystore(),
         task_manager: &mut task_manager,
         transaction_pool,
         rpc_builder: rpc_extensions_builder,
@@ -623,7 +596,7 @@ where
     // if the node isn't actively participating in consensus then it doesn't
     // need a keystore, regardless of which protocol we use below.
     let keystore = if role.is_authority() {
-        Some(keystore_container.sync_keystore())
+        Some(keystore_container.keystore())
     } else {
         None
     };
```

Any ideas where this error might come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I tracked the error to https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/cb954820a8d8d765ce75021e244223a3b4d5722d and the solution is to add `BabeDeps` dependency that uses `babe_worker_handle` to instantiate the RPC extensions (that seem to be mandatory for 0.9.42).

```rust
diff --git a/node/src/rpc.rs b/node/src/rpc.rs
index 039e43e..cb13628 100644
--- a/node/src/rpc.rs
+++ b/node/src/rpc.rs
@@ -26,29 +26,47 @@ pub use sc_rpc_api::DenyUnsafe;
 use common_runtime::Block;
 use common_runtime::{AccountId, Balance, Index};
 use jsonrpsee::RpcModule;
+use sc_consensus_babe::BabeApi;
+use sc_consensus_babe::BabeWorkerHandle;
 use sc_transaction_pool_api::TransactionPool;
 use sp_api::ProvideRuntimeApi;
 use sp_block_builder::BlockBuilder;
 use sp_blockchain::{Error as BlockChainError, HeaderBackend, HeaderMetadata};
+use sp_consensus::SelectChain;
+use sp_keystore::KeystorePtr;
 use std::sync::Arc;
 
+/// Extra dependencies for BABE.
+pub struct BabeDeps {
+    /// A handle to the BABE worker for issuing requests.
+    pub babe_worker_handle: BabeWorkerHandle<Block>,
+    /// The keystore that manages the keys of the node.
+    pub keystore: KeystorePtr,
+}
+
 /// Full client dependencies.
-pub struct FullDeps<C, P> {
+pub struct FullDeps<C, P, SC> {
     /// The client instance to use.
     pub client: Arc<C>,
     /// Transaction pool instance.
     pub pool: Arc<P>,
+    /// The SelectChain Strategy
+    pub select_chain: SC,
+    /// A copy of the chain spec.
+    pub chain_spec: Box<dyn sc_chain_spec::ChainSpec>,
     /// Whether to deny unsafe calls
     pub deny_unsafe: DenyUnsafe,
     /// Manual seal command sink
     pub command_sink_opt: Option<
         futures::channel::mpsc::Sender<sc_consensus_manual_seal::EngineCommand<sp_core::H256>>,
     >,
+    /// BABE specific dependencies.
+    pub babe: BabeDeps,
 }
 
 /// Instantiate all full RPC extensions.
-pub fn create_full<C, P>(
-    deps: FullDeps<C, P>,
+pub fn create_full<C, P, SC>(
+    deps: FullDeps<C, P, SC>,
 ) -> Result<RpcModule<()>, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>
 where
     C: ProvideRuntimeApi<Block>,
@@ -56,10 +74,13 @@ where
     C: Send + Sync + 'static,
     C::Api: substrate_frame_rpc_system::AccountNonceApi<Block, AccountId, Index>,
     C::Api: pallet_transaction_payment_rpc::TransactionPaymentRuntimeApi<Block, Balance>,
+    C::Api: BabeApi<Block>,
     C::Api: BlockBuilder<Block>,
     P: TransactionPool + 'static,
+    SC: SelectChain<Block> + 'static,
 {
     use pallet_transaction_payment_rpc::{TransactionPayment, TransactionPaymentApiServer};
+    use sc_consensus_babe_rpc::{Babe, BabeApiServer};
     use sc_consensus_manual_seal::rpc::{ManualSeal, ManualSealApiServer};
     use substrate_frame_rpc_system::{System, SystemApiServer};
 
@@ -67,13 +88,30 @@ where
     let FullDeps {
         client,
         pool,
+        select_chain,
+        chain_spec,
         deny_unsafe,
         command_sink_opt,
+        babe,
     } = deps;
 
-    module.merge(System::new(client.clone(), pool, deny_unsafe).into_rpc())?;
-    module.merge(TransactionPayment::new(client).into_rpc())?;
+    let BabeDeps {
+        babe_worker_handle,
+        keystore,
+    } = babe;
 
+    module.merge(System::new(client.clone(), pool, deny_unsafe).into_rpc())?;
+    module.merge(TransactionPayment::new(client.clone()).into_rpc())?;
+    module.merge(
+        Babe::new(
+            client.clone(),
+            babe_worker_handle.clone(),
+            keystore,
+            select_chain,
+            deny_unsafe,
+        )
+        .into_rpc(),
+    )?;
     if let Some(command_sink) = command_sink_opt {
         // We provide the rpc handler with the sending end of the channel to allow the rpc
         // send EngineCommands to the background block authorship task.
diff --git a/node/src/service.rs b/node/src/service.rs
index 55443d3..eb636f6 100644
--- a/node/src/service.rs
+++ b/node/src/service.rs
@@ -218,6 +218,7 @@ pub fn new_partial<RuntimeApi, Executor>(
                 FullGrandpaBlockImport<RuntimeApi, Executor>,
             >,
             sc_consensus_babe::BabeLink<Block>,
+            sc_consensus_babe::BabeWorkerHandle<Block>,
             sc_consensus_grandpa::LinkHalf<
                 Block,
                 FullClient<RuntimeApi, Executor>,
@@ -237,13 +238,6 @@ where
         RuntimeApiCollection<StateBackend = sc_client_api::StateBackendFor<FullBackend, Block>>,
     Executor: sc_executor::NativeExecutionDispatch + 'static,
 {
-    /*if config.keystore_remote.is_some() {
-        return Err(ServiceError::Other(
-            "Remote Keystores are not supported.".to_owned(),
-        ));
-    }*/
-    // TODO deprecated ?
-
     let telemetry = config
         .telemetry_endpoints
         .clone()
@@ -297,37 +291,36 @@ where
         client.clone(),
     )?;
 
-    let import_queue = if consensus_manual {
-        sc_consensus_manual_seal::import_queue(
+    let slot_duration = babe_link.config().slot_duration();
+    let (import_queue, babe_worker_handle) = sc_consensus_babe::import_queue(
+        babe_link.clone(),
+        babe_block_import.clone(),
+        Some(Box::new(justification_import)),
+        client.clone(),
+        select_chain.clone(),
+        move |_, ()| async move {
+            let timestamp = sp_timestamp::InherentDataProvider::from_system_time();
+
+            let slot =
+                sp_consensus_babe::inherents::InherentDataProvider::from_timestamp_and_slot_duration(
+                    *timestamp,
+                    slot_duration,
+                );
+            Ok((slot, timestamp))
+        },
+        &task_manager.spawn_essential_handle(),
+        config.prometheus_registry(),
+        telemetry.as_ref().map(|x| x.handle()),
+    )?;
+
+    // Shadow import_queue
+    if consensus_manual {
+        let import_queue = sc_consensus_manual_seal::import_queue(
             Box::new(babe_block_import.clone()),
             &task_manager.spawn_essential_handle(),
             config.prometheus_registry(),
-        )
-    } else {
-        let slot_duration = babe_link.config().slot_duration();
-        let (import_queue, _) = sc_consensus_babe::import_queue(
-            babe_link.clone(),
-            babe_block_import.clone(),
-            Some(Box::new(justification_import)),
-            client.clone(),
-            select_chain.clone(),
-            move |_, ()| async move {
-                let timestamp = sp_timestamp::InherentDataProvider::from_system_time();
-
-                let slot =
-                    sp_consensus_babe::inherents::InherentDataProvider::from_timestamp_and_slot_duration(
-                        *timestamp,
-                        slot_duration,
-                    );
-
-                Ok((slot, timestamp))
-            },
-            &task_manager.spawn_essential_handle(),
-            config.prometheus_registry(),
-            telemetry.as_ref().map(|x| x.handle()),
-        )?;
-        import_queue
-    };
+        );
+    }
 
     Ok(sc_service::PartialComponents {
         client,
@@ -337,7 +330,13 @@ where
         keystore_container,
         select_chain,
         transaction_pool,
-        other: (babe_block_import, babe_link, grandpa_link, telemetry),
+        other: (
+            babe_block_import,
+            babe_link,
+            babe_worker_handle,
+            grandpa_link,
+            telemetry,
+        ),
     })
 }
 
@@ -363,21 +362,9 @@ where
         keystore_container,
         select_chain,
         transaction_pool,
-        other: (block_import, babe_link, grandpa_link, mut telemetry),
+        other: (block_import, babe_link, babe_worker_handle, grandpa_link, mut telemetry),
     } = new_partial::<RuntimeApi, Executor>(&config, sealing.is_manual_consensus())?;
 
-    /*if let Some(url) = &config.keystore_remote {
-        match remote_keystore(url) {
-            Ok(k) => keystore_container.set_remote_keystore(k),
-            Err(e) => {
-                return Err(ServiceError::Other(format!(
-                    "Error hooking up remote keystore for {}: {}",
-                    url, e
-                )))
-            }
-        };
-    }*/// TODO deprecated ?
-
     let grandpa_protocol_name = sc_consensus_grandpa::protocol_standard_name(
         &client
             .block_hash(0)
@@ -398,11 +385,9 @@ where
         Vec::default(),
     ));
 
-    //let mut net_config = sc_network::config::FullNetworkConfiguration::new(&config.network);
     let (network, system_rpc_tx, tx_handler_controller, network_starter, sync_service) =
         sc_service::build_network(sc_service::BuildNetworkParams {
             config: &config,
-            //net_config: net_config,
             client: client.clone(),
             transaction_pool: transaction_pool.clone(),
             spawn_handle: task_manager.spawn_handle(),
@@ -497,7 +482,7 @@ where
                     client: client.clone(),
                     pool: transaction_pool.clone(),
                     commands_stream,
-                    select_chain,
+                    select_chain: select_chain.clone(),
                     consensus_data_provider: Some(Box::new(babe_consensus_data_provider)),
                     create_inherent_data_providers: move |_, _| {
                         let client = client_clone.clone();
@@ -521,7 +506,7 @@ where
             let babe_config = sc_consensus_babe::BabeParams {
                 keystore: keystore_container.keystore(),
                 client: client.clone(),
-                select_chain,
+                select_chain: select_chain.clone(),
                 block_import,
                 env: proposer_factory,
                 sync_oracle: sync_service.clone(),
@@ -568,23 +553,22 @@ where
 
     let rpc_extensions_builder = {
         let client = client.clone();
-        //let keystore = keystore_container.sync_keystore();
         let pool = transaction_pool.clone();
-        //let select_chain = select_chain.clone();
-        //let chain_spec = config.chain_spec.cloned_box();
+        let select_chain = select_chain.clone();
+        let chain_spec = config.chain_spec.cloned_box();
+        let keystore = keystore_container.keystore().clone();
 
         Box::new(move |deny_unsafe, _| {
             let deps = crate::rpc::FullDeps {
                 client: client.clone(),
                 pool: pool.clone(),
-                //select_chain: select_chain.clone(),
-                //chain_spec: chain_spec.cloned_box(),
+                select_chain: select_chain.clone(),
+                chain_spec: chain_spec.cloned_box(),
                 deny_unsafe,
-                /*babe: crate::rpc::BabeDeps {
-                    babe_config: babe_config.clone(),
-                    shared_epoch_changes: shared_epoch_changes.clone(),
+                babe: crate::rpc::BabeDeps {
+                    babe_worker_handle: babe_worker_handle.clone(),
                     keystore: keystore.clone(),
-                },*/
+                },
                 command_sink_opt: command_sink_opt.clone(),
             };
```